# Alternative to sys.exit(0) when running a script within a loop?

Tags: python

I have a loop of the form:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys


range_start_date = '2020-01-01'
range_end_date = '2020-01-10'
daterange = pd.date_range(range_start_date, range_end_date) # creates a range of dates list

for d in daterange:
    start_date = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    exec(open("run_transactions.py").read())
```

Within run_transactions.py I have a particular line of code like this:

```
import sys
if transactions.shape[0] == 0:
     sys.exit(0)
```

I do this because further down in the script I apply some data wrangling to data frame called transactions. But, sometimes transactions has no data, in which case I exit.

However, since I am calling the script as part of a loop, with a new date d on each loop iteration, I don't want to exit the program entirely, instead I want to skip the rest of the script only, then continue the loop.

Is there a way for me to tell python that if `if transactions.shape[0] == 0` then to stop running this iteration of run_transactions.py and to proceed to the next part of the loop? Using sys.exit(0) exists the program entirely and breaks the loop which is not what I want.

Comment: try using break, continue or pass based on your requirements.

Comment: Reading a script and `exec`ing it is pretty crude code reuse. Why not put the logic of that script into one or more functions, and then you can `import` the module and run them as desired. The functions can `return` early if they don't have anything useful to do, or maybe raise an appropriate exception.

Comment: you really need to used exec ?

Comment: @parlad continue wouldn't work because it's not "properly" in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `try...except` to your `exec()` instruction:

```
## Your code
## ...
for d in daterange:
    start_date = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    try:
        exec(open("run_transactions.py").read())
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

And in your `transaction.py` you can just keep using `sys.exit(0)`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

> `sys.exit([arg])`
>
> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the `SystemExit`
>   exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try
>   statements are honored, and **it is possible to intercept the exit
>   attempt at an outer level**.

So basically you intercept that execption and just ignore it and keep running your loop.

**EDIT:**

Example of use:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    try:
        exec(open("file.py").read())
    except SystemExit:
        print(f"System Exit on i = {i}")
    else:
        print(f"Normal {i}")
```

`file.py`:

```
import random
import sys

x = random.randint(0, 5)
if x >= 3:
    print("sys.exit(0)")
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print(f"{x} is smaller than 3. No sys.exit(0)")
```

An example (due to the `random` behavior) **output:**

```
1 is smaller than 3. No sys.exit(0)
Normal 0
sys.exit(0)
System Exit on i = 1
sys.exit(0)
System Exit on i = 2
2 is smaller than 3. No sys.exit(0)
Normal 3
sys.exit(0)
System Exit on i = 4
```

Comment: Hi, I gave this a try but it did still sys exit when instead I hoped that it would pass and move to the next iteration of the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to print the exception to see if I had used the wrong one `    try:
        exec(open("run_transactions.py").read())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)` but this still didn't catch, I just got 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Comment: @DougFir, edited answer with an example of use. It works fine. Maybe there is something on your code that you are not telling us.

Answer (score 1):

Would it work if we just use "return"?

```
if transactions.shape[0] == 0:
     return
else:
     your code (happy path)
```

Comment: Hi yes, I think this might work but it would imply the rest of the script is part of an else block. I wonder if there's a way to tell python to just abandon script but not program

Comment: Hey, you're right, this wouldn't be ideal even if it works. Following for other solutions..

Comment: You could remove the `else` statement and just do the rest of the code at the same indentation level of the `if` statement. That `else` is just useless.